# flutter just_audio_background error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'

Tags: flutter, android-manifest, just-audio

Am trying to set up [just_audio_background](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background) but get a bunch of errors (as per screenshot), when I follow the amendments to the main/AndroidManifest.xml and not sure why as appears to follow the steps exactly as the plugin outlines.

The warnings I get are:

[image: warnings]

And the exception reason I get when I run the app is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: Error parsing /Users/mac/Documents/flutter_projects/zense_timer_project/zense_timer/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

And here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <application
        android:label="zense_timer"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->

        <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:exported="true" tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- ADD THIS "RECEIVER" element -->
        <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"
            android:exported="true" tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <!-- ADD THIS "SERVICE" element -->

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have run flutter clean and restarted but still can't fix these errrors.

Note possibly related, my AndroidManifest does have these warnings before I make amendments for just_audio_background, but my app still compiles fine and from what I read might be related to a bug in the IDE.

```
Unresolved class '{applicationName}'
Unresolved class '{applicationName}'
Cannot resolve symbol '@style/NormalTheme'
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of manifest (before add plugin changes)]

[image: And screenshot with the plugin changes]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest file,

**Change this**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

**To this**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't work in my case, I still have the same errors.

Comment: It should work. Could you please share the screenshot of your modified manifest? @Kdon

Comment: I added 2 screenshots (before and after plugin changes) this shows my manifest seems to have issues before being modified. I also tried start a brand new flutter project and had these warnings still (Unresolved class '{applicationName}') so seems an issue with how my manifest is configured and not the just_audio_background package. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs carefully and follow step by step to Edit the AndroidManifest.xml file in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

My file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<application
    android:label="learn_english"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

    <activity
        android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        >
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />

    <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
        android:exported="true" tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"
        android:exported="true" tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).